# Using same VIEW again and again (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-linearlayout

I working on an app where i have a dedicated menu at the bottom which contains some fixed buttons that have same function and behave in same way on all the activities.
I tried using the same ID of Button(View) in different activities but it isn't working. Also i searched a lot didn't find any way
Is there is any way that i can share a View or View Group in more then one activities ?

For example i create this layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/childLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button2" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Is there is any way that this layout id ="childLayout" can be used in any other activity which is inside layout id = "parentLayout"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the suggestions [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html)?